# Datetime field not in sync in Transactional Replication - does default value matter?

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I run 2012 SQL Server and I use the Transactional Replication to sync data to the replication server. I have no control over the application which uses the database.

- There is a table with the column `ChangedWhen`, `DEFAULT VALUE GETDATE()`.
- The App does `INSERT("varchar","varchar"...)`  -> and relies on the Default value for `ChangedWhen`
- The `ChangedWhen` in the replicated database differs from the main database (anything between 200ms to 10s), as it most likely uses `GETDATE()` instead of a value.

I ran Wireshark to analyse what the application does.

I expect to have `CreatedWhen` column in sync with the replication, so the latency between the insert and actual insert in replication db doesn't affect the value of the column. Has anyone experienced anything similar?